# Titanium: generate IPA without device

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium, provisioning-profile, ipa

I developed an iOS app using Titanium on a macbook. I need to create the IPA file for allowing  other testers to try my app on their devices (via TestFlight). I have no iPhone nor iPad, but accordingly to plenty of articles on the web this is not a problem at all.

BUT, I need a Provisioning Profile and I cannot create one without a device.

So, **how can I compile?**

Comment: You don't need a device to have a provisioning profile. You only need an apple developer account. You need a distribution certificate, an adhoc provisioning profile, and for your testers to register their devices on TestFlight.

Comment: @JosiahHester I've got dev account, dev and distribution certificate as well as appId. But when I try to create a provisioning profile, Apple ends up with asking for a device, with its name and UDID. Is there another way to get it?

Comment: Josiah told you what you need to do, and my answer below tells you as well. I added step-by-step instructions to my answer in case that helps.

Comment: The device(s) it is asking for are the testing devices, which you need to add after people register those devices on TestFlight, as detailed in Gavin's answer.

Comment: You could also read the guide -- http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Distributing_iOS_apps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to compile it to be installable on their devices via TestFlight, you must add their devices to your account and then add those to the provisioning profile. Then you can build the app and upload it to TestFlight.

The way TestFlight works is that when you add testers to your team, it will send you their device UDIDs. Then you will go to the iOS developer portal and add them to your devices list, then you'll (re)create the provisioning profile with those devices added.

EDIT:

I don't know why I was downvoted for a right answer, but in case clear steps are necessary, here it is:

1. Create TestFlight account
2. Do "Add Application" so that you have your app entry in the TestFlight system
3. Invite your testers to your team
4. Wait for your testers to accept, and add their devices to their TestFlight account
5. Take the UDIDs for their devices that TestFlight sends you, and go enter those devices into your iOS developer account
6. Create your provisioning profile using those devices that you just entered
7. Create your IPA using that provisioning profile
8. Upload your IPA to TestFlight
9. Give your testers permission to download the build from the Permissions tab in TestFlight

I think you were making the incorrect assumption that you needed the IPA first, which is not true. TestFlight is first the mechanism to get the UDIDs of your testers devices, before you create the IPA. After that, TestFlight is your mechanism to distribute the app to your testers. I and many other people have done exactly the above steps many times, and you can be assured that you don't have to have the IPA first, you only create it *after* you have the device UDIDs of your testers.

Comment: your answer is totally right, but that's not the point. Problems issue earlier, I don't even get the IPA to share with TestFlight. I know every device should be registered, but I have no Apple device so I'm looking for a way to compile for the others who do have.

Comment: Why the down vote? And @balanza, you don't need the IPA right away to create the app entry in TestFlight. You go on TestFlight, create your app, and invite users. It's AFTER you invite users, and they accept, that you get their UDIDs. THEN you go back to the iOS dev portal to add their devices, so that THEN you can create the provisioning profile, so that THEN you can create the IPA, which you THEN upload to TestFlight. What I said is not just right, it is the solution to your problem.

Comment: This is correct. And the approach I have followed for a hundred different builds. +1

Comment: mmm ok, now I got what you meant. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
ti build -p ios -T dist-adhoc
```

or

```
ti build -p ios --deploy-type production --ios-version 9.0 --keychain --target dist-adhoc --output-dir
```